# Html5 Drag&Drop, with popup window for uploading the dropped files to the server (asp.net)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html, file-upload

I'm using HTML5 drag and drop upload in my site (asp.net web application).
the upload process needs to be executed in a popup window with progress bar for each file (so the page that contains the drag area will keep running asynchronize).
I need to access the files from the server (C#) and not only from javascript. 
The problem is that context.Request.Files is empty in the popup window. when i tried writing all code in the same page Request.Files was full.

Here is my code:

opening the popupwindoe from the "parent" page (jquery):

```
 function handleDnDFileSelect(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        /* Read the list of all the selected files. */
        files = event.dataTransfer.files;
        var fileCount = files.length;
        // Only call the handler if 1 or more files was dropped.
        if (fileCount > 0) {
            window.open("UploadProgress.aspx", "progress", 'menubar=1,resizable=1,width=750,height=450');
        } 
    }
```

uploadProgress.aspx:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;
    var files = window.opener.files; //files is full corectly
    var form = document.getElementById('form1');
    var data = new FormData(form);
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) //creating a new XMLHttpRequest for each file
    {
        data.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', "UploadProgress.aspx");
        xhr.send(data);
    }
});
</script>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server" data-ajax="false" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<asp:Repeater ID="rptFilesUpload" runat="server">
 <ItemTemplate>
    <div id="progressbar">
        <asp:Label ID="lblFileName" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItem %>' ></asp:Label>
    </div>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</form></body>
```

uploadProgress.aspx.cs:

```
public partial class UploadProgress : System.Web.UI.Page, IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
        HttpFileCollection fileCollection = context.Request.Files;// Session["Files"] as HttpFileCollection;
        ArrayList FilesNames = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < fileCollection.Count; i++)
        {
            HttpPostedFile upload = fileCollection[i];
            string filename = "c:\\Test\\" + upload.FileName;
            upload.SaveAs(filename);
            //update arrayList for the repeater
            FilesNames.Add(upload.FileName);
        }
        rptFilesUpload.DataSource = FilesNames;
        rptFilesUpload.DataBind();
    }
```

What am i doing wrong?
I'm looking for a solution for days.........
I will appreciate any try to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still dont know why it didnt work.
but, I just put the ProcessRequest function in ashx (handler) 
and change  xhr.open('POST', "UploadProgress.aspx");
to xhr.open('POST', "UploadProgressHandler.ashx");
and it worked!
(only in FireFox and Chrome. In IE(10+) I still looking for solution)